# Let $l' > l > 0$. Construct a PRG that would transform any PRG of stretch $l$ into one of stretch $l'$

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

The way I understand this question is that we have a secure PRG G: $\{0,1\}^\lambda \rightarrow \{0,1\}^{\lambda + l}$, and we want to use it to make a secure PRG G' : $\{0,1\}^\lambda \rightarrow \{0,1\}^{\lambda + l'}$ which is essentially $\{0,1\}^\lambda \rightarrow \{0,1\}^{\lambda + l + k}$ where $k$ is $l' - l$.

I have tried many different constructions of G' by feeding in keys to G, but none of them work out in the end (length wise) unless we assume that $l'$ is a multiple of $l$.

Another way I thought to construct G', but I think won't work, is to get the first $\lambda + l$ bits from G and then randomly generate the last $l' - l$ bits. Then we can concatenate and return this value. However, this would violate the fact that PRGs must be deterministic so running G' with the same seed multiple times would yield different results in this case.

Any suggestions on how to approach this problem? I think perhaps I may be overthinking it.

Comment: Sounds like a homework problem. Have you seen any example of converting a small-stretch PRG into a larger-stretch PRG?

Comment: If $G$ is a PRG, and we define $G'$ to work by running $G$ and cutting off some of the trailing bits, is $G'$ a PRG?

Comment: @Mikero I'm reading through the book "Joy of Cryptography" by Mike Rosulek. There is one example of doubling the PRG stretch, but the proof uses the fact that the new stretch is a multiple of the old one.

Comment: @Maeher That is a good idea. I thought about implementing that but I never saw that technique utilized in the book so I was unsure how to formally include cutting off trailing bits in a PRG construction.

Comment: Hint: If you uniformly sample some bits, and throw some away, are the remaining ones still uniform? PS: great textbook, I know the author well. :)

Comment: @Mikero Thanks for pointing me on the right track. I think I can take take it from there. Super cool you know the author.

Comment: @BB33 concat `Mike` and `Rosulek` and substring(0,6), what do you see?